# How do I disable the On-Screen Keyboard on Windows 7?

Tags: laptop

I need help to disable the on-screen keyboard, It is highly annoying every time I restart or turn on my PC. Can anyone please tell me how to turn it off?

Answer (score 3):

It's under the Ease of Access Center. Go under "Use Computer without mouse & keyboard" and turn it off there.

**Edit**

If it is on the login screen, there is a button on the bottom. . .

Answer (score 1):

In the Control Panel, go to Ease of Access Center, then go to Use the computer without a mouse or keyboard, uncheck Use On-Screen Keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Click on "Options" on the on-screen keyboard ITSELF (right bottom corner).
Almost on the bottom of the window you will find "Control whether the on-screen keyboard starts when I log on" link.
Uncheck the "Use The On-screen Keyboard" box. 
Click "Apply".
Done.

Answer (score 0):

Open up your "Services".

- Press Windows key + R, type "services.msc" and press Enter
- Scroll down to "Touch screen keyboard and handwriting panel"
- Right click this service and select "stop"
- Right click this service again and select "properties"
- In the pop up select "disabled" or "manual" in the dropdown

It now won't start on a computer reboot.